# Use case in where clause

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I am trying to add case statement to where condition in a query.
My query looks like below-

```
select * from table_name
where
if(id==1) then col1 = 0
else           col1 is null
```

As shown in above query I want to add col1 = 0 in where condition if id-==0 else I want col1 is null in where condition.
I tried

```
select * from table_name
where 
case id =1 then (col1 = 0)
else col1 is null
end
```

But the syntax is incorrect.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not `Where (id = 1 AND col1 =0) OR (id <> 1 AND col1 IS NULL)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE isnull(id, '')= CASE(id)
               WHEN 1
               THEN 0
               ELSE ''
           END;
```

Comment: equal comparison with NULL ( id = NULL ) i dont think it will work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your requirement but you can try if below satisfies you

```
select * from table_name
where 
isnull(col1,'') = case when id = 1 then   0
else '' end
```

Also try

```
select * from table_name
where 
( col1 = 0 and id = 1) OR ( col1 is null and id<>1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a case when solution. Which can be used as below to fill in a specific column. You do need to select the other columns as well when you do this though.

```
select 
case when id = 1 then 0 else null end as col1
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select case when id = 1 then 0 else null end as col1, * from table_name
```